# System.import in angular 2 always try to import from url

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

Here is my html:

```
<script src="/static/angular-scripts/vendors/test/es6-shim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/angular-scripts/vendors/test/angular2-polyfills.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/angular-scripts/vendors/test/system.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/angular-scripts/vendors/test/Rx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/angular-scripts/vendors/test/angular2.dev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
     }
    }
   });
 System.import('angular/core')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

The above code will output:

```
GET http://my_url/angular/core 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How would you config SystemJS so that it doesn't find the path literally from the url, is there a way to config against it?

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with angular/core.it is API of anuglar2 that comes from the url that you added above.
Normally we use System.import to import boot file.
Heres the example,

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/router.dev.js"></script>
 <script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript', 
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: I couldn't import my boot file either, I was trying to test if I can import anything at all.

Comment: i have edited my answer with the src links,cuz im not sure you are having the correct versions. and if you try that, it will look for the file in the following url. For example boot file in app,                                 **localhost:8080/yourPROJECTname/app/boot.ts**